# Case comments visible in the UI but not in SOQL

Tags: case, visibility

I have a case with several comments:

[image]

When I try to get those comments via SOQL (same user on dev console), I got no results:

[image]

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

Your screen shot shows `Text Posts` tab. These are Chatter FeedItems of type Text Post.

Case Comments are not chatter feed items.

To query [standard object FeedItems](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_chatter.htm?q=caseFeed)

```
SELECT Body, ...
 FROM CaseFeed
 WHERE ParentId = 'yourCaseId'
```